# string to datetime format conversion using python

Tags: python, datetime

```
stime = '2015-08-20T06:43:18.733Z'
start_time = time.strptime(stime,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

I am getting this time from the database, and it is in form of string. I tried searching on how to convert this string to date time format and found this solution in one of the questions on this site. But in this time format there are letters too. How do I remove these? Please help.

I got following error while running the code:

```
ValueError: time data '2015-08-20T06:43:18.733Z' does not match format
'%Y-%m-%d T %H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Sorry if this is a very basic question. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me in python 2.7

Comment: In error your time format is `'%Y-%m-%d T %H:%M:%S.%fZ'` which has space around `T`. and it works with `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"`

Comment: It is not working for me, could you suggest any alternative. I am using python 2.7 only.

Comment: with or without space i got same error. I was trying if that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the format string that you posted exactly. It's working on my end with Python 2.7. The ValueError is showing spaces around `T` like Kasramvd said.

This works:

```
stime = '2015-08-20T06:43:18.733Z'
start_time = time.strptime(stime,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

This perfectly replicates your error:

```
stime = '2015-08-20T06:43:18.733Z'
strformat = '%Y-%m-%d T %H:%M:%S.%fZ'
start_time2 = time.strptime(stime, strformat)

ValueError: time data '2015-08-20T06:43:18.733Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d T %H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried again, and I don't know why before I got the error, but now same thing is working fine. but can you tell me how to get that milliseconds also, because it returns only seconds. I need to add milliseconds also for further manipulation.

Comment: You need to use `datetime` for that. `start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(stime,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")` gives us: `datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 6, 43, 18, 733000)` and `start_time.microsecond` = `733000`.